# where do I put code in Sinatra that I want to execute when the app is shutdown?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I am using Sinatra for my webapp. I have some cleanup code that I want to execute when my app is being shutdown. Is there a hook for this in Sinatra or do I have to use a separate mechanism?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Look at [Kernel#at_exit](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-at_exit), I don't see why it shouldn't work in a Sinatra app if you define a block like that somewhere in your main app file.

**Update:** According to matt's comment, you have to define your `at_exit` handler before requiring Sinatra.

Comment: I was under the impression that only gets called once all threads have exited. I will go test that myself. One of the specific things I need to do is shutdown some threads, so if that's the case, that won't work for me.

Comment: This might not work, depending on how you start Sinatra, since [Sinatra uses `at_exit` itself](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/v1.3.2/lib/sinatra/main.rb#L25) to start its built in server, so any `at_exit` handler you add will actually run _before_ Sinatra starts.

Comment: Interesting. I wonder if I should delete my answer or keep it around for the time being. Maybe I'll wait until @pquimo reports back.

Comment: Turns out that threads will be just shutdown unless of course you call join on them.  So theoretically at_exit might work.  It's not really what I was hoping for. But I've also asked in IRC, and only got the at_exit there also. It makes me wonder if I'm approaching the problem the wrong way, so I'm going to take a step back and ponder more, and probably hammer out some code to explore the problem more fully. Normally I would have first, but I expected this to a be a relatively simple answer that I just was struggling to find.

Comment: I’ve just done a quick test with this — if you add the `at_exit` handler _before_ you call `require 'sinatra'` then your handler gets called after Sinatra shuts down, since it’s at the bottom of the `at_exit` stack. So this could be a useful technique in some cases.