# How to handle traps in Sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I want to capture traps and need to execute custom code before exiting my Sinatra application. I need to wait till my thread execution completes before exiting from Sinatra.

```
require 'sinatra'

trap('INT') do
 puts "Trapped"
 @th.join
 exit(99)
end

get "/test" do
 "Hello World!"
 @th = Thread.new {sleep 30}
 puts @th
end
```

If I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> it should wait till the thread completes.

Comment: So what doesn't work?

Comment: If I press Ctrl+C it is immediately getting terminated , That is how usually sinatra works , I need use custom traps for my sinatra application .

Comment: Rather than capturing traps, have you tried [`at_exit`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11105556/where-do-i-put-code-in-sinatra-that-i-want-to-execute-when-the-app-is-shutdown)?

Comment: I can't use thread.join  with at_exit  because  the variable is not getting transferred to  at_exit function
undefined method `join' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)  - I am testing immediately  after the "get /test" call

Comment: That’s because `at_exit` won’t inherit the instance variables of the Sinatra app. Try setting `thread=nil` before your `at_exit` function and then saying `thread = Thread.new { … }` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`at_exit`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11105556/where-do-i-put-code-in-sinatra-that-i-want-to-execute-when-the-app-is-shutdown) to run code before your app shuts down.

If you need to use variables in `at_exit` that you don't have until runtime, you can try just making them global. For example,

```
thread = nil

at_exit do
  puts "Trapped"
  thread.join if thread
  exit(99)
end

require 'sinatra'
get "/test" do
  "Hello World!"
  thread = Thread.new {sleep 30}
  puts thread
end
```

Comment: Require 'sinatra' must be after defining at_exit

Comment: Interesting, ok.